# Libgdx & Box2dLights - can't get rid of black background

Tags: libgdx, box2d, light

Let's get some code:

```
public MyScreen implements Screen{
    logo = new Texture(/**/); // loading some images

    // initializing the RayHandler
    rayHandler = new RayHandler(new World(new Vector2(0f,0f), false));
    rayHandler.setShadows(false);
    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.WHITE.r,Color.WHITE.g,Color.WHITE.b,1);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(logo,logo_pos.x, logo_pos.y, logo.getWidth(),logo.getHeight());
    batch.end();

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

    rayHandler.updateAndRender();
}
```

When I worked with LibGDX before, I used the same code above but with a background texture. Everything was fine when I disabled shadows.

Now I don't want to use a texture, but a single color (white, as shown above).
**The problem is here, that the background is BLACK, but! my logo texture is visible.**

Somehow rayHandler is applying the black background and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or I just can't combine Box2dLights with a background color. Should I use a background texture with my desired color and set it as a background, or is there a solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean that when you start the appl, the whole screen is black? Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of the two calls, `glClearColor` and `glClear`, as follows:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.WHITE.r, Color.WHITE.g, Color.WHITE.b, 1f); // White
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

In your code, the screen is cleared before the colour is set...